# How to fetch content via shortcode in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I am using a shortcode to get content of a page. The shortcode runs well when added in the wp editor but it does not seem to work or better I say it's not parsed when it comes via ajax.

I have a popup on the site which displays WooCommerce product info via Ajax. The shortcode shows only raw codes and do not get parsed. This is the shortcode

```
function fetch_content_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    global $post;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => null
    ), $atts));
    ob_start();
    $output = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $id));
    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('fetch-content', 'fetch_content_shortcode');
```

The shortcode `[fetch-content id="1234"]` works fine when added in a text editor but not with Ajax. Any help will be appreciative.

Comment: it's working fine here in ajax. can you please send me demo url?

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. Please see these two URLs https://ayanize.com/dev1/ (click the Quick Look button) and this URL https://ayanize.com/dev1/product/demo-product/. The image of the man holding is ear is the content fetched from a page ID which does not show up when clicked on the Quick Look button.

Answer (score 0):

For product "Product Short Description" is not content of the product if you want to get that field then add below code.

```
/* If you want content of page, post or product */
$output = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $id));
/* If you want excerpt of page, post or product */
$output = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $id));

Shortcode to get product excerpt:

function fetch_content_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    global $post;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => null
    ), $atts));
    ob_start();
    /* If you want excerpt of page, post or product */
    $output = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $id));
    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('fetch-content', 'fetch_content_shortcode');
```

**This code is tested and working perfect.**

Comment: Thanks for this but this is not the point here. The shortcode is indeed fetching post content but this is added in an excerpt as you can see. It's working on the single product page where it's added in WC short description box but not parsing the Divi shortcodes when they are called in the ajax popup

Comment: to get excerpt that code is working fine also in ajax